# fetch() json from php

Tags: javascript, php, json, fetch

I've got a I've got a simple fetch request. I'm not much of an expert in promises and asynch code but from what I understand fetch url sends a request to open/get/post an url and returns a promise (response) of delivering that content. Qhen that content is fetched THEN I can parse it in a text (response.text() ) the parsed text/json, whatever, is then passed to another function as data and here processed

** JS CODE **

```
fetch(url).then(function(response) {
    console.log(typeof(response));
    return response.text();
}).then(function(data) {
    console.log('data ', data);
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log ('ERRORE ', err);
})
}
```

so if I'm fetching a php url wich returns a json, when I console.log the data in I should see the html code echoed by the php and the json inside it, instead all I see is a string of numbers like 1137168 (I typedof it and it's a string...)

** PHP CODE **

```
$selectNum = "SELECT num FROM table";
$quer = mysqli_query($conn, $selectNum);  
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($quer, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $arrayJSON = $row;
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($arrayJSON, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); 
mysqli_close($conn);
```

the php and the js are saparated files

Comment: header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);  use this on server side

Answer (score 0):

You need to set headers to json on server side and use json_encode to the array you want to return on your request like :

```
<?PHP
$data = /* your array */;
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

and parse it on client side using jquery like so

```
var data = /*data retuned from your request*/;
$.parseJSON($data);
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: I've added the php file in the question. I used json_encode and qhen I look just at the php file it seems ok

Comment: try setting headers like i did above

Comment: I tried adding the header before the echo output (like in the code in the question) but the result is still the same. I also changed the response.text into response.json, just to be sure, but still nothing changes

Comment: Paste what you see in console .. Also do you see a JSON option along with HTML under the request in console ?

Answer (score 0):

On your while block you are not using concatination, so your $arrayJSON contains the last row's num you selected in the query.

Comment: no, actually it contained it all, that was the problem. I finally figured out that it gave me back all the results from mysql but they were formatted in a weird way, so what it looked like a random string of numbers was, really, my result a little unorganized and mixed up. Thank you both for your help :)